# Using Yago2s through Jena

Tags: java, jena

I plan to use **Yago2s using Jena TDB through Java**. I found the java project to convert the Yago dump into Jena format [here](https://code.google.com/p/my-funny-stuff/source/browse/trunk/+my-funny-stuff/yago-converters2/). I loaded this project in Eclipse and ran **Converter.java** which asked me to specify the folder containing **YAGO relation definitions**(the data folder, containing relations.tsv). It specifically said that this file wasn't the dump of Yago. Now, I don't know where this folder exists. All I have on my system is the 
the Yago2s dump in ttl format downloaded from the [website](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/downloads/). The website has nothing called relations.tsv(though there are four files under taxonomy). Can anybody help me about what to do here?

Also, the readme.txt file [here](https://code.google.com/p/my-funny-stuff/source/browse/trunk/%20my-funny-stuff/yago-converters2/info/readme.txt) says that Yago in Jena TDB format is available on the website. Is this referring to the .ttl format or .tsv format ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a `.ttl` file you can load that directly into TDB (or any RDF store). No conversion needed, just `tdbloader`.

Comment: @user205512...Thanks...can you point me to a resource which has info on how to do that?

Comment: Sure: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/commands.html#tdb-commands. However you just need `tdbloader --loc <TDB DIRECTORY> file.ttl`.

Comment: @user205512...thanks